# Subiquity Random crashing on Dell Precision 3660

Tags: apt, dell, vmware, subiquity

We've been developing an cloud_init/autoinstall for Dell Precision 3660, the majority of the work, because it was quicker was developed and written in house using virtual machines on VMware vSphere 7.0.3 and 8.0.1, and the cloud_init/autoinstall from cdrom and webserver serving user-data and meta-data worked perfectely.

But the ultimate goal, is to issue pen drives to install unattended on Dell Precision 3660 in a lab of 30 workstations, and this is where the issue occurs, the machines to intermittently fail to install and Subiquity randomly crashes!

There is no pattern we can observe, sometimes at Kernel install, sometimes before grub is installed, sometimes after initial start. It's very odd.

I'll grab the crash logs and upload.

Comment: it crashes mostly at Installing Kernel

Comment: I've been reworking and removing items from the config user-data to see if it's anything specific